# Exercice base for SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I've been trying to show that Ker(K^T) is the same set as the orthogonal of Im(K) for SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) purposes. I did half of it as you can see in the image below, so can you help me? how do I finish it?
[image: SV]

K is a matrix representing a linear transformation.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: I don't know how to use, I'm sorry

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. See [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers.
Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.